# Наследуется ли список инициализации при наследовании конструктора?

Tags: c++

Есть следующий конструктор:

```
Teacher(int Salary,int number_of_teaching_gr):Person(arr,42),  Salary(Salary),  number_of_teaching_gr(number_of_teaching_gr)
{

}
```

- в списке инициализации явно вызывается нужный конструктор базового класса.
  В другом классе - наследую этот конструктор:

  ```
   class Head_of_Departaament :Teacher
      {
        public:
         using Teacher::Teacher;
      };
  ```
- как я понимаю, после наследования, данный класс теперь так же имеет такой же конструктор у себя - т.е конструктор добавляется в этот тип , но если это так, то происходит ли "полное наследование" - т.е я имею ввиду, что после унаследования конструктора, теперь, при вызове его в этом классе, он так же явно будет вызывать указанный конструктор базового класса? Т.е  Head_of_Departaament и так - т.к наследуется от Teacher - вызовет его конструктор, а тот - конструктор Person, но , допустим у меня у Teacher - будет два конструктора, которые отличаются только вызовом конструктора базового Person(которых, так же предположим, будет несколько), то в таком случае, при наследовании конструктора из Teacher - какой конструктор Person будет вызываться?

Comment: насколько мне известо, конструкторы не наследуются. В примере выше благодаря using просто добавляются идентичные конструкторы для наследуемого класса, который при вызове только и делают, что дергают соответствующий конструктор базового.

Comment: Добрый вечер. Если я Вас правильно понял, то вызывается соответвующий "наследуемый" конструктор из базового для Head_of_Departaament  -класса  Teacher - конструктор, который в своем списке инициализации вызывает соответсвующий  конструктор Person? Но для меня так и осталось неясным, как определяется, какой именно конструктор "дергать", если они будут отличаться только вызовом конструктора в списке инициализации?

Comment: об этом ниже написал HolyBlackCat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Наследуется ли список инициализации при наследовании конструктора?

Конечно да, иначе конструкторы бы постоянно ломались от наследования.

> допустим у меня у Teacher - будет два конструктора

Тогда конструктор будет считаться перегруженным, и будет происходить [разрешение перегрузки](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

Наследование конструкторов тут не при чем. Если бы вы напрямую работали с объектами `Teacher`, было бы то же самое.

> два конструктора, которые отличаются только вызовом конструктора базового Person

Как это? Вот так?

```
Teacher(int Salary,int number_of_teaching_gr) : Person(arr,42), Salary(Salary) /*...*/ {}
Teacher(int Salary,int number_of_teaching_gr) : Salary(Salary) /*...*/ {}
```

Так как параметры совершенно одинаковые, при объявлении второго конструктора получите ошибку о недопустимой перегрузке, вроде:

> ```
> error: 'Teacher::Teacher(int, int)' cannot be overloaded with 'Teacher::Teacher(int, int)'
> ```

Параметры двух конструкторов должны как-то отличаться друг от друга, чтобы в каждом конкретном случае компилятор мог выбирать, какой конструктор больше подходит (если подходит) под переданные аргументы.